# Centralized Credentials

Tags: architecture, saas

I am looking to setup testing & staging environments. We have many config parameters that depends on environment i.e on test environment it should send out email to xyz@test.com while on production it should send email to xyz@production.com. Also, we are using many third-party services (i.e Salesforce, PayPal) that provides separate credentials/URL to access test environments.

I am thinking of creating a secured web service that will return value for a given key based on request IP address. i.e if request is from testing server machine then it will return xyz@test.com while if same code is running in production it will return xyz@production.com

Basically, I want to keep my code & config deployment easier to manage.

Can you please review and suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF the list of properties that you are considering to configure for each environment is small, then you can achieve that reliably from a build environment, where the build can pick up from properties file the required details. However the risk is running production credentials on a development environment, for that you need to be careful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the mechanism you're describing is known as (enterprise) single sign-on. Maybe there is a fitting solution already available?

If there isn't a fitting solution already available, I'd rather use different hashes to identify test/production server instead of IP address, because the latter can change quite easily